# option to align a label near the scatterplot circle

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, d3.js

I am working with d3.js and rendering a scatter graph. I want to have the label exactly above and near the scatter plot area.

[Here is my graph](http://alignedleft.com/content/3.tutorials/10.d3/140.making-a-scatterplot/demo/3.html).

I am trying to center the label above and make it near the scatter plot circle. Is there any `.attr()` property to add padding to the text so that it can be displayed exactly above the bubble and also near it?

I was able to get the text in the middle of the scatter using `.attr("text-anchor","middle")`, but i need the text to be closer to the scatter chart. Right now it is 4px away from the scatter plot circle.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by setting the text anchor to `middle` and adding an offset to the `y` coordinate:

```
svg.selectAll("text")
   ...
   .attr("y", function(d) {
     return d[1] - 10;
   })
   .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
   ...
```

Jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vLekX/).

Comment: Yes thanks Lars. i have used this .attr("text-anchor","middle"). but is there any option to make it near the scatter plot circle. any help would be appreciated

Comment: You can adjust the `y` coordinate offset to get the text closer to the circle.

Comment: I am now using rickshaw.js. Any suggestions for this Lars.because d3 works without any changes in the y axis offset.